# Qt многопоточность в работе с БД

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Появилось проблема в оптимизации приложения которая работает с БД(MySQL).
Есть весьма большой SQL запрос(выборка с множеством inner join) который выполняется в конструкторе и на основе него строится UI.
И ПО висит во время запроса, а это плохое поведение пользователи сейчас нервные приложение могут и закрыть...
Я бы хотел перенести работу с БД в отдельный поток но к сожалению я не имел опыта в этом.

Можно ли минимально работающий пример работы много поточного приложения где один поток рисует UI и занимается бизнес логикой а другой работой с БД.
А я бы оттолкнулся от этого примера и переписал бы свой.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Но если от данных из БД зависит содержимое каких-то элементов UI, то что будет рисовать главный поток в то время, когда поток работы с базой будет ждать результат запроса? Вероятно, надо максимально облегчить запуск приложения. Может, использовать какой-то кэш предыдущего запуска?

Comment: Ну... я решил это с помощью "костыля". Результат запроса поместил в другую таблицу а дельта изменений вносится туда. И теперь выборка занимает не 2 минуты а 2 секунды.
Но все ровно это весьма затратно.

Answer (score 1):

Пример подобного кода можете посмотреть в моем гите:
класс инкапсулирующий QSqlDatabase и предоставляющий шаблонные методы для вызова в другом потоке: [тыц](https://github.com/bronstein87/dbhandler/blob/master/database/database.h).
Пример использования можете найти тут: [тыц](https://github.com/bronstein87/dbhandler/blob/master/dbanalyzewindow.cpp).
Если вкратце, то нижеприведенная связка методов:

```
template <typename DB, typename Function , typename ...Args, typename CallBack, typename ReturnValue, typename ConnSetter>

    QUuid Database::callAsync(DB* db, ConnSetter&& setter, QFutureWatcher<ReturnValue>* watcher, Function&& query, CallBack&& callBack, Args&& ...args)
    {    
        auto id = prepareToAsyncCall(watcher, std::forward<CallBack>(callBack));
        QFuture<ReturnValue> futureValue
                = QtConcurrent::run(
                    bind(
                        exceptionWrapper <DB, ReturnValue, Function, ConnSetter, Args...>, id, watcher, db, forward<Function>(query), setter, forward<Args>(args)...));
        watcher->setFuture(futureValue);
        return id;
    }
    
    
    template <typename DB ,typename ReturnValue, typename Function ,typename ConnSetter, typename ...Args>
    auto Database::exceptionWrapper (QUuid id, QFutureWatcher<ReturnValue>* w, DB* db, Function function, ConnSetter setter, Args& ...args)
    -> decltype((db->*function)(args...))
    {
        try
        {
            QScopedPointer <DB> tempDbConn(new DB(id));
            setter(tempDbConn.data());
            QObject::connect(tempDbConn.data(), &Database::queryCanceled, tempDbConn.data(),
                             [w](){w->disconnect(); w->cancel();}, Qt::DirectConnection);
            db->setConnectionOptions(tempDbConn.data());
            return (tempDbConn.data()->*function)(args...);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            throw ThreadDbException(e);
        }
    }
```

Позволяет вызвать любой метод класса `Database` в потоке, получить результат через QFuture и если что вернуть в главный поток исключение.
Если возникнут какие-либо вопросы, то можете написать мне на почту (она указана в профиле).

Comment: а одновременный запуск нескольких запросов не приводит к аду и израилю из-за отсутствия какой-либо синхронизации в `QSqlDatabase`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, при вызове в потоке подключение полностью копируется и запрос выполняется через копию.

Comment: правда... долго не мог найти, где — не заметил, что QSqlQuery принимает его по-значению...